# Remove values from a given variable in the Enviroment C

Tags: c, path

I have this function where i m trying to remove the values of a given variable from the path. The problem is that i do not know how to set my enviroment variable to the new value after deleting the last string each time separated by semicolons.

For example if my variable is:

WEATHER = hot;cold;dry

to become

WEATHER = hot;cold

```
int remove(char name_Remove[]){
  char *value_toRemove = getenv(name_Remove);
  char *pos = strrchr(value_toRemove, ';');

  if(pos) {
    *pos = 0;
    return pos-name_Remove;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Also i already have a function which adds variables and values to the enviroment if this helps of the form of:

```
void add(char name[], char value[]) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A call to [setenv](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/setenv.html) should do it. This will only update the current environment though, so any change to the environment variables will only take effect for the current process.

I don't think it's possible to change the environment variables in the parent process (i.e. the shell) without execing your process from bash.

Comment: i just want to change the child process enviroment variables values can you show me how to do it?

Comment: In that case, use the setenv call that I showed, the linked page should give you a decent idea of how to use it.